# Dependency Injections seems to create new doctrine instance, which causes an entity to be detached)

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine, symfony4

I've got two services, those get Doctrine injected via the constructor. When loading an entity in an EventListener and giving it ot service the entity is detached.

When im providing the DoctrineEntityManager from an EventListener to service, the entity is still managed.

```php
class Listener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /** @var EntityManagerInterface */
    private $em;

    /** @var Service */
    private $service;

    /** @var EventDispatcherInterface */
    private $eventDispatcher;

    public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface $em,
        Service $service,
        EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher
    ) {
        $this->em = $em;

        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
        $this->service = $service;
    }


    public function listenerFunction(Event $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getEntity()->getUser();
        var_dump($this->em->contains($user)); // true

        $this->service->func($this->em, $user);
    }
}

class Service
{
    /** @var EventDispatcherInterface */
    private $eventDispatcher;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em, EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
    }

    public function func($em, $user)
    {
        var_dump($this->em->contains($user)); // false 
        var_dump($em->contains($user)); // true
    }
}
```

the services yaml

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: true

  App\Payment\Command\:
    resource: "%kernel.project_dir%/src/Payment/Command/*"
    tags:
      - { name: console.command }

  App\Payment\Service\:
    resource: "%kernel.project_dir%/src/Payment/Service/*"

  App\Payment\Controller\:
    resource: "%kernel.project_dir%/src/Payment/Controller/*"

  App\Payment\EventSubscriber\:
    resource: "%kernel.project_dir%/src/Payment/EventSubscriber/*"
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

The EntityManager in the service should contain the $user entity. Im thinking symfony is creating a second instance of the entitymanagerinterface here, but the says there is only one instance of each item (https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/shared.html)

Comment: definitely sounds weird and normally doesn't match any experience I have had so far with DI in symfony. tbh, I would suspect something fishy happening somewhere, but unable to point out where, since your code obviously is incomplete. But i guess the services.yaml would be a good place to start.

Comment: @Jakumi thank you for your response, the same on my side, thats why I created this thread. Regarding the EM there is just a flush and no clean or something. I've added the services yaml to the thread.

Comment: okay, nothing particularly suspicious there. let's try the windows-solution and turning it off and on again, meaning ... scrap the vendor dir, composer install (also clears the cache, i believe)

Comment: Maybe it's too early but I can't tell which event you are listening to.  In any event (hah) $event->getEntityManager() will give you the actual event manager.  Using it may or may not help the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by updating all packages (composer update) yay ;D